# How to Split a string onto an array using "," but string(s) may be of more then one length/number of delimiters? (Python 2.7)

Tags: arrays, string, python-2.7, split

I receive messages from an AMQP feed as strings. I am able to receive the string and create an array using split on "," characters as is shown below:

```
T_MSG = msg

    TM = T_MSG.split(',')
    onT, item, t_b, t_a, t_stamp, = \
        TM[0], TM[1], TM[2], TM[3], TM[4]
```

This works in as much as I can reference the parts of the message received using the array/list location (e.g. TM[0]) or the variable name I assigned it (e.g. OnT) which I am happy with however...

**(Actual Question)**

The messages I can receive have a varying length/number of delimited fields, which can be one of three lengths/number of delimiters, so I am getting range out of bounds errors when processing them as the code I use above expects the number of delimiters/message length to always be the same...

Is there a way to split a string based on a "," and assign the components to an array which I can then reference in my program even if the length of the message/number of delimiters is one of three possible lengths?

**For example:**

```
Msg0: xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,
Msg1: xx,xxxxx,xxx,xxxx,xxxxx,xxx
Msg2: x,xxxx,xxx
```

How can I create a piece of code in Python 2.7 that can handle splitting the 3 message lengths shown above on "," and assign the components of each message to its own array/list, based on the message length. (I only want/need 3 lists\arrays - as I am happy for the list/array to be updated/overwritten as each new message is received and split...)

At the moment I am stuck as I am not sure how to use conditions based on the message length/number of delimiters to do this and if I craft the code to work for the longest message then it fails (generates an out of bounds error) when the shortest message type is received and vice-versa...

Any pointers much appreciated - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I was able to count the number of delimiters and then use elif statements to process the messages as needed - in case this is useful for anyone else I have posted the code I used below:

```
T_MSG = msg
T_MSG.count(',')

    if  T_MSG.count == 4:
        TM = T_MSG.split(',')
        onT, item, t_b, t_a, t_stamp, = \
        TM[0], TM[1], TM[2], TM[3], TM[4]

    elif T_MSG.count == 5:
        TM1 = T_MSG.split(',')
        onT1, item1, t_b1, t_a1, t_stamp1, tt_owa1 = \
        TM1[0], TM1[1], TM1[2], TM1[3], TM1[4], TM1[5]

etc...
```

I hope this may be useful for others...